# ElasticSearch geo distance filter with multiple locations in array return the matched geopoint

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a documents in an ElasticSearch index. Each documents has multiple locations in an array, like this:

```
{
    "name": "foobar",
  "locations": [
    {
      "lat": 40.708519,
      "lon": -74.003212
    },
    {
      "lat": 39.752609,
      "lon": -104.998100
    },
    {
      "lat": 51.506321,
      "lon": -0.127140
    }
  ]
```

I have created a geo distance filter which checks all the locations in the array and returns the entire document with has matched geo point in their array

I wolud like to know if there is a way to get the closest matched point in the array along with each result document?